# Why are the two events independent of each other in this case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

For the following problem, the two events are said to be independent of each other.

[image: a]

Intuitively, I would think that the outcome of `10` depends on getting `5` on both rolls, which gives a `YES` answer.  Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Use the mathematical definition of independence.

Comment: As you say, knowing your sum is 10 clearly changes the probability of getting at least one 5, which says the events are DEPENDENT, i.e. a NO answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you!  Figured out my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply mixed up the linguistics of the question, by ignoring a negation. Inititally you say

> For the following problem, the two events are said to be independent
>   of each other.

That is **no**t what is indicated in the picture. The question asks if the events are $\color{red}{\rm in}\rm dependent$, and "No" is presented as correct. That's the same as saying they are dependent.

Which is what your intuition told you and which paw88789 proved in their answer.

Your inituition and the answer (from an online test, I presume) agree. They are just worded differently ("dependent" vs. "not independent").

Comment: Thank you!  I was absent-minded.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $A$ be the sum is $10$ (as in OP's statement), and letting $B$ be the event of at least one $5$, then:

$P(A)=\frac{5}{25}$

$P(B)=\frac{9}{25}$

and $P(A\cap B)=P(A)=\frac{1}{25}$.

Since $P(A\cap B)\ne P(A)\cdot P(B)$, the events are not independent.

One could also reason that event $A$ is a subset of event $B$.  So $P(B|A)=1\ne P(B)$